# Double escaping Regular Expressions in Craft's Twig replace filter?

Tags: templating, regex, replace

Just trying to use Craft's Twig replace filter to remove number prefixes from the beginning of User Groups names and I have had to double escape the character classes etc to get it to work. I tried this...

```
{{ group.name|replace('/^\d+\.\s/','') }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
```

and it didn't work so for some reason I tried this...

```
{{ group.name|replace('/^\\d+\\.\\s/','') }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
```

...and it worked. Is there a sensible explanation for this as Regular Expressions are like Voodoo?!

Comment: Meant to say the docs show only single backslashes hence the confusion...

Comment: Neal, I came across the same mystery using Twig's `matches` operator, which was also wrong in [Sensiolabs' docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#comparisons).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twig auto-escapes the `\` character so by the time it makes it to the Craft [replace](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/etc/templating/twigextensions/CraftTwigExtension.php#L140) filter PHP code, the regex string looks like `/^d+.s/`.

By double escaping it, you're forcing the correct regex to make it through `/^\d+\.\s/`.

Comment: Glad there is a sensible explanation... is this documented anywhere for future reference?

Comment: Is now! http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#replace

Comment: Awesome, thanks Brad!

Comment: This is not a Craft-CMS related comment, but I want to say I could only use the `matches` operator in TWIG to validate a string against a regular expression when I used double-escaping in my regexp.