# Escape characters in format

Tags: templating, datetime, escaping

I'm trying to find a method of escaping characters in Craft's `DateTime` object.

This is the output I'm trying to achieve: `16th January 2016`

This is what I've tried: `{{ article.postDate.format('j\<\s\u\p\>S\<\/\s\u\p\> F Y') }}`

This is the output: `16&lt;00000000p&gt;th<!--00000000p--> January 2016`

I can achieve the output by appending output together but there **has** to be a better way of achieving this than the following:

`{{ article.postDate.format('j') }}<sup>{{ article.postDate.format('S') }}</sup> {{ article.postDate.format(' F Y') }}`

Any pointers to documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trial and error I figured out you can escape characters using double backslash.

```
{{ article.postDate.format('j\\<\\s\\u\\p\\>S\\<\\/\\s\\u\\p\\> F Y') | raw }}
```

Outputs: `14<sup>th</sup> January 2016`

In search of documentation I found a mention of [double-escaping regular expressions](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4271/4118) due to Twig auto-escaping `\`. At this point I'm guessing this works for most Craft-Twig functions.

Answer (score 3):

Try the Twig [`date`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html) filter instead:

```
{{ article.postDate|date('jS F Y') }}
```

to wrap the ordinal in `<sup>`:

```
{{ article.postDate|date('j') }}<sup>{{ article.postDate|date('S') }}</sup>
{{ article.postDate|date('F Y') }}
```

if you think it's to ugly for use in your templates, consider "hiding" it in [a macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html).

Comment: I tried that as well, but I'm looking to put a `sup` element around the ordinal suffix. I'd do this using the date function by escaping the characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Craft 3, the [Typogrify](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft3-typogrify) plugin will do the `<sup>` on ordinal numbers automatically for you.